# Can moderators please provide me links to all my posts that have been deleted?

Tags: discussion, support

Can moderators please provide me links to all my posts that have been deleted? I am constantly looking for some posts but realize they have been deleted and how cheerful it is. For example, I am looking for all my posts related to tier or MVC or architecture.

I have read from https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/searching

> When you earn the Access to Moderator Tools privilege, you may search
> your own deleted posts by using the deleted: operator.
>
> Site Moderators may use this operator to search all posts on the site, including those owned by other users.

I was wondering what this policy is based on?

What does this policy want to achieve?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, I can't tell you why it's so difficult for a user to see their own deleted posts. That policy really doesn't make sense to me. It does make sense that you would need to achieve a threshold to see other people's deleted posts (there's probably a reason why they were deleted, and not everyone single person needs access to those).

I can, however, help you identify all of your deleted posts. As of today, [you have 29 deleted posts](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A699%20deleted%3A1), all of which are questions:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/302669/convert-a-colored-photo-to-a-black-white-scan
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95609/the-smallest-memory-units-addressible-and-movable
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/269677/does-programmer-use-device-files-as-interface-to-device-drivers-in-their-program
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/235808/distribution-release-and-version
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/298938/what-is-collision-domain
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/393889/how-is-the-soa-pattern-different-from-the-client-server-pattern
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274724/differences-between-books-in-the-principles-of-computer-programming-and-in-prog
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/341963/how-can-i-guess-the-purpose-of-a-class-and-identify-its-most-important-methods-a
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/275367/what-aspects-do-a-programmer-and-language-designer-implementer-need-to-know-abou
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/301290/how-is-the-state-of-a-program-defined-and-can-there-be-a-wrong-state-earlier-th
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257318/encoding-for-a-text-with-math-symbols
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274086/differences-between-core-cpu-processing-element-processor-processing-unit-f
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/333671/why-does-the-quicksort-algorithm-in-clrs-not-have-the-base-case
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/275341/programming-languages-syntax-and-semantics-with-design-and-implementation-and
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/393558/what-style-of-software-design-is-soa-supposedly-opposed-to
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/393860/what-are-the-differences-between-concurrency-computational-models-and-concurrenc
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/394058/what-are-the-differences-and-relations-between-activity-and-action
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/392945/why-soa-was-proclaimed-dead
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/389607/what-are-the-differences-between-generally-available-production-ready-sta
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278000/concepts-for-a-programming-language-similar-to-environment-and-environment-varia
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/333729/does-quicksort-for-increasing-order-work-faster-if-the-input-set-is-more-decreas
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/299392/relation-and-difference-between-connection-channel-and-medium
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93944/flynns-taxonomy-and-task-parallelism-and-data-parallelism
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/301291/program-errors-and-syntax-semantics-errors
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62571/do-you-wear-gloves-to-work-on-computers-in-cold-environment
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/347552/what-is-business-logic-opposed-to-in-a-software-system-used-for-some-business-pu
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/302000/a-model-of-computation-vs-an-abstract-machine
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/271579/does-a-gpu-have-multiple-processors-each-of-which-is-a-vector-processor
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/393891/is-broker-a-design-pattern-and-mentioned-in-design-patterns-by-gamma-et-al

Comment: difficulty is there because 8 years ago [Atwood believed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/53297#comment222981_53297) that "it would lead to unbelievable amounts of whining". This belief has been thoroughly proven wrong after people were allowed to see part of their deleted posts that are less than 60 days old, but system hasn't been corrected to reflect that